# Connect selected bar (vizframe barchart) to a button

Tags: button, charts, linker, sapui5, selection

I already have a barplot ui5 vizframe, but I would like to allow the user to select some of those bars, add each element id to a list and then send the list through a button in order to display a more detailed graph on a fragment.xml view.

On my picture example, the selection is mathematics, ASP and C#.

Here is the view.xml for the main graph panel:

```
<f:Card class="sapUiTinyMargin tileLayout" width="96%" visible="{config>/useFeatureEnableDemoFunctionality}">
    <f:layoutData>
        <grid:GridItemLayoutData gridRow="span 2"/>
    </f:layoutData>
    <f:header>
        <card:Header title="Skills popularity" subtitle="List of skills and tools ordered by how many people mentioned it in their profile"/>
    </f:header>
    <f:content>
        <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}" height='100%' width="100%" vizType='bar'>
            <viz:dataset>
                <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{path:'/PopularSkills', length: 30, sorter:{ path: 'MembersCount', descending: true }}">
                    <viz.data:dimensions>
                        <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Label" value="{Label}"/>
                    </viz.data:dimensions>
                    <viz.data:measures>
                        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Popularity" value="{MembersCount}"/>
                    </viz.data:measures>
                </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
            </viz:dataset>
            <viz:feeds>
                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Popularity"/>
                <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Label"/>
            </viz:feeds>
        </viz:VizFrame>
        <!--<Button icon="sap-icon://log" class="sapUiTinyMargin" text='Analyse selection' press="ButtonSkillSelection"/>-->
    </f:content>
</f:Card>
```

Rendered chart:

[[image: vizframe graph]]

Answer (score 0):

This is a method to retrieve selected items in the VizFrame:

```
<Button press=".onPress"/>


onPress: function(){
 const selectedSkills = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame").vizSelection();
 //Do something useful with your selection
}
```